# Docusign API - DateSignedTabs Timezone

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Is there a way I can control which timezone to use when a signer signs the Document and the `DateSignTab` is auto-populated? I'm running tests signing from my computer, and the first signature is using EST while the second is using PST.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can only be controlled by the recipient, if they have a DocuSign account, in their preferences they can select their timezone option. If the recipient does not yet have a DocuSign account - this will default to the account's timezone.